# How do you make a Variable decrease every time a button is clicked by the value of another Variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, button, var

I'm trying to make a button that decreases a variable-defined number by another variable-defined number every time it's clicked. 
Example: 
[Button] 
Number: 500 
**Button Clicked* 
[Button] 
Number: 475 
**Button Clicked Again* 
[Button] 
Number: 450 
And so on.. 
I'd love to give code and what not but I can't even get it close to working so that would be useless..

Comment: No more homework please.Try something and we will let you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code could look like this:

```
var count = 500;
var decrementAmount = 25;

function reduceVariable() {
   count -= decrementAmount;    
}
```

Then, just call reduceVariable from your button click.

Comment: Much more simple than I expected,would it be possible for it to be reset when it hits 0 making another var = true as easily?

Comment: @SusuReedJango - yes that is possible, but like some of the other comments say, you need to show some sense of learning/researching how to do things and trying something.  I'd suggest you go look at how an `if` statement works in javascript.  Here's [one place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to look.

Comment: I've looked for an answer on many websites and video tutorials for this in particular over the span of a few days, and got one here in under ten minutes.. Was mainly making sure it was possible. I'll look into it and try out things now, thank you for your help and simplicity! I'll go on now. Hah.

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da3YR/4/)

HTML:

```
<div id="text">500</div>
<p><input type="button" id="button" value="Decrease me"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
var oButton = document.getElementById("button");
var oText = document.getElementById("text");
var count = 500;
oButton.addEventListener('click', function(i, a) {
    oText.innerHTML = count -= 25;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as example:

HTML:

```
<span id="spnTest">500</span>
<button id="btnTest" >Decrease</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var ratio = 25;
var totalValue = 500;

function decrease(){
    if(totalValue == 0) return;
    totalValue -= ratio;
    document.getElementById('spnTest').innerHTML = totalValue;
}
document.getElementById('btnTest').onclick = function(){ decrease(); }
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69SvR/4/)

Comment: Sorry try it again. I have just update jsfiddle, my code is fine